# Lebesgue Integral and Gradient

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, vector-analysis

I am currently studying on Mixed Method to solve Stokes Equation. I encounter this problem when it says $p:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ has a zero-mean over a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\int_{\Omega}p dx = 0$. May I know how should I understand this statement?

Also, given $\int_{\Omega}p dx = 0$ and $\nabla p = 0$ over $\Omega$, why does this imply $p=0$? I know these may be basic knowledge on Lebesgue Integral, but I hope someone can explain it clearly. Thanks.

Comment: For the first questin, it mean that $\frac{1}{|\Omega |}\int_\Omega p=0$. For the second question, if $\nabla p=0$, then $p$ is constant a.e. Say $p=C$ a.e. If $0=\int_\Omega p=C|\Omega |$, then $C=0$, and thus $p=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Lebesgue measures, nonempty open sets (as a domain $\Omega$ must be) have positive measure. The mean of a function $f$ on $\Omega$ is defined to be $\frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)}\int_{\Omega} f\ dx$, so if this equals zero, the desired integral must of course equal zero.

To show the second statement, $\nabla f = 0$ on $\Omega$ implies that $f$ is constant on $\Omega$. If you want to justify that, suppose $f(x)\ne f(y)$. Then we can find a path $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ connecting $x$ to $y$ such that the path is piecewise composed of segments in which only one coordinate changes. Then, apply the mean value theorem to each of these segments, as you would in single variable calculus. Having justified this, if $f = C$ on $\Omega$, then $0 = \int_{\Omega} f\ dx = \mu(\Omega)C$ implies that $C = 0$ since $\mu(\Omega) \ne 0$.